# EF(4) Detach an object from the context, outside the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i've created an object A, and i want to store (add) it twice with the EF.

So i have a method `Save(Order order)` in my repository.

But when i do this:

```
Order order = new Order();
//set props here
new Repository().Save(order);
new Repository().Save(order);
```

then i get an error because in the first save it (the order) keeps some reference to the context.
Can i, between the two Save call's, say '*please release yourself from the context, and pretend you're as new as before the first Save()*' so i can save it again?

Comment: Does your order have an unique ID? if so try to set it to before the 2ed save order.id =0;

Comment: yep, it has an unique id. I'll try that too.

Comment: unfortunately no luck: System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'OrderId' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `context.Detach(order)` do the trick?

Comment: i'll give that a try. Is it only possible on the CONTEXT, not on the OBJECT (in this case the order) itself?

Comment: @Michel - you can do it on the `ObjectSet<T>` too (which is preferred, as with `.Attach`). E.g `ctx.Orders.Detach(order)`.

Comment: RPM is right, but of course having access to the `ObjectSet` will require pretty much the same effort on your part as having access to the whole context. You can't call Detach on an entity as in "detach yourself from whatever your context is".

Comment: Ok, thanks Jon for your comment. So am i right when i say you can only detach yourself from the context when you're in scope of the context, but outside of the context the object still carries 'knowledge' of the context?